# Auto-mount a Volume Group on Startup?

Tags: mount

I have two physical volumes ( /dev/sda3 and /dev/sdb1 ) connected to one volume group (fileserver). When I boot up my computer and open up the file explorer, on the left, I see a Devices pane that says my volume group. However, I cannot connect to this server from any client until I click it. Clicking the volume group mounts it because it shows the eject arrow sign right next to it. As soon as I click it, then I am able to connect to the server and see my files.

My question is: how do I automate this process every time Ubuntu starts? I tried going to the Startup Applications and using this command

```
    mount /dev/mapper/fileserver-media /media/bfbe53bd-3306-401b-a8df-4363564cf1fc
```

but it didn't seem to do anything. I attached a picture to show what I mean.

This is what it looks like when I turn on my computer. http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a582/sameetandpotatoes/Before_zpsa67a3e4f.png

Now, this is what it looks like when I click on the device: http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a582/sameetandpotatoes/2_zps5c91a322.png

Here are the Terminal outputs of pvscan, vgscan, etc.

**sameet@sapraserver:~$ sudo pvscan**

PV /dev/sda3   VG fileserver   lvm2 [216.07 GiB / 18.89 GiB free]

PV /dev/sdb1   VG fileserver   lvm2 [232.83 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 2 [448.89 GiB] / in use: 2 [448.89 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

**sameet@sapraserver:~$ sudo vgscan**

Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...

Found volume group "fileserver" using metadata type lvm2

**sameet@sapraserver:~$ sudo lvdisplay**

--- Logical volume ---

LV Name                /dev/fileserver/media

VG Name                fileserver

LV UUID                lrY16C-bNwH-fFvA-aVDW-Gtx6-2vIG-urrGpD

LV Write Access        read/write

LV Status              available

# open                 2

LV Size                430.00 GiB

Current LE             110080

Segments               2

Allocation             inherit

Read ahead sectors     auto

currently set to     256

Block device           252:0

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out finally. Here's what I did:

1. First, I made sure I had the right Logical Volume name by running `lvdisplay` in terminal.
2. Then, I had to edit the `rc.local` file in `/etc/rc.local`. I added the command there because I couldn't run a command as root in the Startup Applications (I would have to enter a password). In this file, for my system I added the following command:

   ```
   mount /dev/fileserver-media /media/
   ```

   The /dev/fileserver-media is the name of the logical volume (found with lvdisplay). The /media/ represents where I want the logical volume to be mounted.
3. And then with Samba, I ran `gksudo nautilus` in the terminal, edited permissions, and shared it. The reason I ran this command in the terminal is to open up the file manager as root so I can be the "owner". I would not have been able to edit permissions without running this command.

Answer (score 2):

You should just add a line in your `/etc/fstab/` like

```
/dev/fileserver-media /media/ ext4 defaults 0 0
```